# JS clearInterval does not delete the intervaID

Tags: javascript

I want to build a stopWatch. You can start and pause.  My approach. I start a setInterval and when pause is clicked, I delete the intervalID and set intervalID (global) to zero. However, the interval is not deleted. What am I doing wrong? I suspect that I am assuming something wrong. I expect the interval ID after clear and restart to be the same and not the next higher number.  I use Firefox on OS.

My code:

```js
const o = document.querySelector("div");
const b = document.querySelector("button");
let intervalID = null;
let timer;

b.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (intervalID !== null) {
    console.log("instance already running lets clear Interval by IntervalIdD");
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    console.log("interval_cleared",intervalID);
    intervalID = null;
    return;  
  } 
  
  intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(123)
  }, 1000);

  console.log("interval",intervalID);
})
```

```html
<div>0</div>
<button>Start / Stop</button>
```

Comment: Why do you expect the `intervalID` value to be the same when you create a new interval?

Comment: This value could be anything. For instance in node.js it's an object not even a number. In HTML specs it's expected to be an "implementation-defined integer that is greater than zero and does not already exist in global's map of active timers", but you can't assume anything else about this integer. Imagine, if it did work as you expected, and that you stored the intervalID in two different components. If the id was reused, when the second component will try to stop the already stopped timeout, it would stop another unrelated one.

Comment: @Nick I guess that's my fault. I expect the same number as IntervalD, as I had deleted it shortly before. I want to be sure that there are not hundreds of intervals running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Since your interval is globally defined and you are able to clear it. I do not think there will any intervals running in the background.

Though, you might see different results if its not defined globally, example in react's useEffect method.

Below is the modified example for timer, let me know what you think.

```js
const o = document.querySelector("div");
const b = document.querySelector("button");
let intervalID  = null;
let count = 0;

b.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!intervalID ) {
    intervalID  = setInterval(function() {
      o.innerText = count++;
    }, 1000);
    return;
  }
  console.log("instance already running lets clear Interval by IntervalIdD");
  console.log("interval_cleared", intervalID );
  clearInterval(intervalID );
  intervalID  = null;

})
```

```html
<div>0</div>
<button>Start / Stop</button>
```

---